# Send data from notification to active Class without restarting intent

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I am sending a notification Data payload from my server to my devices using FCM. When the app is closed or in the background, I am forcing them to restart the login process which is my `Initialize.class` file.

```
Here is the onMessageReceived handler I am currently using.

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.e(TAG, "A notification packet was received from Firebase.");
    if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Type: DATA");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        String image = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
        MyNotificationManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).displayNotification(title, body, image);
    } else if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Type: NOTIFICATION");
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        MyNotificationManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).displayNotification(title, body, "logo");
    }
}
```

When the app is in the foreground however, I am resending the `Browser.class` as intent instead. The problem is when you first run Initialize, it is creating a oneTimeSignOn token and logging you on / creating a new session. Since you are already logged on when you're browsing the app, this is not important to me anymore and I need to just send them the new page the browser class should navigate to without restarting the class.

```
void displayNotification(String title, String body, String image) {
 .....
    Class launchIntent = Browser.class;
    if (isAppIsInBackground(context)) {
        launchIntent = Initialize.class;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, launchIntent);
    intent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_PACKET", "CONTENT");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
}
```

Is there a way to send the payload information to the onResume operator on my Browser.class instead of passing `intent.putExtra`, so I don't need to reload the whole activity? The big problem this is causing is that it stacks multiple browser activities onto the first one.

Is there a better way to check if the activity is offline or just in the background as well? Here is how I currently check

```
private static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
        if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
            for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                    isInBackground = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isInBackground;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to make it work. Not sure if this is hacky or not but it works!

First set the AndroidManifest for the `.Browser` to the following:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Then in the `Browser.class` we add the following method

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

And finally, in the onResume function we overide and add the following tidbit

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("NOTIFICATION_PACKET")) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The following data was received from the notification packet: " + getIntent().getStringExtra("NOTIFICATION_PACKET"));
        getIntent().removeExtra("NOTIFICATION_PACKET");
    }
}
```

Now we can use the packet information and destroy it right away so it's not called again when the app is restarted. This keeps the app at the top of the stack and doesn't restart it while the app is in the foreground. :)